# JSON - Euro exchange rate import to PHP file

Tags: php, json, xml, currency

I have this JSON file: http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/A/EUR/?format=json
and I need to display € exchange rate in my PHP file using echo. I created this but echo displays nothing.

```
<?php
$nbp = file_get_contents('http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/A/EUR/?format=json');
$dane = json_decode($nbp,TRUE);
$kurs = $dane["rates"][0]["mid"];
?>

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>    
<body>
<h1><?php echo $kurs; ?></h1>
</body>    
</html>
```

I doing something wrong? It's my first steps in JSON

Comment: I tried it on my system. Code is working fine.

Comment: are you saying you want to display the `€` sign, as the code display the rates correctly.

Comment: I want to display only euro rate: 4.2911 - I need this to my calculator.

Comment: Are you certain your PHP code is being executed? Only asking because it's a possible explanation of nothing showing up for you when it does for others, and I have no idea of your level of experience.

Comment: I have put my PHP file (that you see above) on my online server, and type in the browser adress of this file. I see white page. Source is showing HTML with <h1> with nothing between. I am not advanced in PHP/JS.

Comment: Okay, that answers my question. If the code wasn't being executed, you'd see the PHP in the page source.